# Preventing MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js from loading

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I've got an ASP.NET web application, and I'm attempting to reduce HTTP calls to the server, so I'd like to not load things like `MicrosoftAjaxWebForms.debug.js` and `MicrosoftAjax.debug.js`.

Script manager is used to form all of my external javascript files into one, and I'm concerned that this is causing other non-related libraries to be loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed the ScriptManager that is pulling these in. You might be able to reduce the number of scripts it adds by turning off the different features on it, eg. `PageMethods`.
Look for the properties that starts with `Enable...`

Of course, it will probably be easier to just create a small method that does the same as the ScriptManager, all it does is add some `<script>` tags to the document..

Comment: They have all been set to false, but the libraries are still loading.

Answer (score 6):

To get rid of the debug versions of the scripts you have to disable debug mode in `web.config`. Find the element called `<compilation debug="true">` under `/configuration/system.web` and change it to `<compilation debug="false">`.

Comment: This helped (at least temporarily) resolve a nasty bug on a website with heavy traffic, thanks for posting.